# Show all running services on Samsung Galaxy S3

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, task-management, services

How can one show all running services on Samsung Galaxy S3?

In system-menu Tinder service for example wasn't shown.

Answer (score 0):

When you go to setting, there are a few options. Depending on which OS version you're running (you haven't provided this but I'm assuming it is a bit old), you can go to the Apps sections and there are 3 tabs 1) Downloaded 2) Running 3) All. You can go to the Running tab to see which processes are running.

Another option is to go to the Memory section and it'll tell you which apps are taking up how much memory on your device. You can also force stop these services here.

Finally there's the battery sections where you can check which app/service is taking up or draining your battery life. You can force stop these apps/services here as well.

It would be best for you to provide the Android OS version so that we can better assist you since the settings and apps occasionally change with each Android OS update.

Comment: Thank you. It's 4.2.2. Task-Manager doesn't show all services. I only noticed them because of a notification. The service is shown in Battery menu only!!!

Comment: You should be able to find which app is taking up Memory. You can enable Developer options by tapping Build number in the About device section multiple times until a congratulations window pops up. In the developer options, there's another option called Process stats. This will show you how much RAM an app takes up. You can then go to settings -> apps and force stops the apps which take up too much memory. Info: http://www.androidauthority.com/how-to-stop-android-apps-running-in-the-background-664842/